# IntelliJ: Java - Annotation processing stops working

Tags: java, intellij-idea, annotation-processing

I'm using IntelliJ 2017.1.4 (latest version) on Linux. It really often happens to me that after switching branches (GIT) the annotation processing stops working even the setting is still enabled. I have to restart the IDE than. Anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: Please [report an issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) with the reproducible test case.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Good idea. Did it.